# Promises es6 and superagent

Tags: ecmascript-6, superagent, es6-promise

I'm attempting to use es6 promises with superagent. I'm attempting to call a function that has a superagent request wrapped inside.

```
Request.post(buildReq).then(res => {
 if (res.ok) {//process res}
});
```

Here is the function wrapping superagent

```
  static post(params) {
    superagent
      .post(params.url)
      .send(params.payload)
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
      .end((error, res) => {
        return this.Promise.resolve(res);
      })
      .bind(this);
  }
```

I'm getting an error

`enter code here Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

When I change the return of the function to

```
static post(params) {
    return Promise.resolve(superagent
      .post(params.url)
      .auth(params.auth.username, params.auth.password)
      .send(params.payload)
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
      .end((error, res) => {
        return this.Promise.resolve(res);
      })
    );
  }
```

It looks like the data is returned in my browser's dev tools, but I cannot get to it within the .then function. How can I get the response from the promise.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It doesn't matter what you're returning from the `end` method callback, as it asynchronously executed when you've get response and result of callback execution is nowhere used. Look [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/blob/master/lib/client.js#L879) and [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/blob/master/lib/client.js#L815) in the source code. `end` method returns `this`, so in your second example you're resolving `superagent` not response. To get response your `post` method must looks like:

```
static post(params) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        superagent
            .post(params.url)
            .auth(params.auth.username, params.auth.password)
            .send(params.payload)
            .set('Accept', 'application/json')
            .end((error, res) => {
                error ? reject(error) : resolve(res);
            });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes you'd like to avoid an indentation level caused by `new Promise(...)` then you can use directly `Promise.reject` and `Promise.resolve`.

```
static post(params) {
    return superagent
            .post(params.url)
            .auth(params.auth.username, params.auth.password)
            .send(params.payload)
            .set('Accept', 'application/json')
            .end((error, res) => {
                return error ? Promise.reject(error) : Promise.resolve(res);
            });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As of [v2.0.0](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/releases/tag/v2.0.0), superagent provides an ES6-compatible `.then()`. So your code could become

```
static post(params) {
return superagent
        .post(params.url)
        .auth(params.auth.username, params.auth.password)
        .send(params.payload)
        .set('Accept', 'application/json')
        .then((res) => {
            return res;
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a more consise version, in case you **need it for a lot of requests**

```
import request from "superagent";

const withPromiseCallback = (resolve, reject) => (error, response) => {
  if (error) {
    reject({error});
  } else {
    resolve(response.body);
  }
};

export const fetchSuggestions = (search) => new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
 request.
    get("/api/auth/get-companies/0/50").
    type("form").
    set("Accept", "application/json").
    query({
      search,
    }).
    end(withPromiseCallback(resolve, reject))
);

export const fetchInitialInformation = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
  request.
    get("/api/auth/check").
    set("Accept", "application/json").
    end(withPromiseCallback(resolve, reject))
);
```

Answer (score -1):

With ES6, you can use async/await with [Promise and Generator support](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#promise-and-generator-support):

```
const res = await request.get(url);
```